# Fetch 2 entities for match and update when there is no relation between them

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am working on hibernate and have this situation.

I have 2 tables TableA and TableB. Both of these tables hold Shop information like Shop name, phone, address, etc. Both of these tables have data populated from 2 different sources and have no relation between them. There are certain data which matches like phone. Considering TableA as the master for information which my application will refer to, I need to compare details in TableB with TableA and update details in TableA when there is a match.

Currently I have to fetch all the data from 2 entities, iterate, compare and update when a match is found. And I have 1500 entries now, but will increase for sure in future. Can anyone suggest a better idea/approach.

Comment: a) introduce batch processing, fetch small portions of TableA and find matches in tableB. However with such approach you will be searching every time the whole TableB content.

Comment: b) introduce.cusom procedure on your database, and make a call to.it — in this case you will be relying on exact sinlgle database implementation, but will gain some performance optimization.

Comment: c) if you can describe your processing like 'update TableA a set field = b.field from TableB b where b.phone = a.phone'

Comment: Thanks IIya. The testing environment is currently in-memory h2 database, but will move to Postgres, so can't rely on custom procedure. I am looking at some solution as you described in option c, but I am not sure how to achieve this. @SecondaryTables was an option, but then there in currently no relationship between the tables and I can't modify it.

Comment: Well `update A from B` should be described as NativeQuery (JPQL doesn't allows explicit joins), and doesn't require foreign keys or something like that in Where clause you are specifying condition "where is match between A and B".